# File disappeared after trying to move it in terminal

Tags: terminal, directory

Can anyone tell me where my file may have gone after this command?

The file I'm missing is stats.cpp

And what is the correct command to move it from directory prog3a to prog3c?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post the actual command you used I cannot tell you what happened to the file. What I can say is that unless you used the rm command, the file is not gone. Probably got its name changed if you cannot find it or it got moved somewhere else other than the intended destination.

The correct command you should use is

```
mv prog3a/stats.cpp prog3c/stats.cpp
```

This command should be run in the directory where both prog3a and prog3c folders exist (cd to it before running the command. This is assuming they're both inside the same directory).

A more specific answer can be provided if you tell us which command you initially ran specifically and the full paths of each folder.